# Elasticsearch 1.5 must not filter works sometimes

Tags: elasticsearch

We noticed the other day that our must_not filter sometimes works. After banging my head on the desk for hours I am here. Any help would be appreciated. Also the erpNumber term could be listed up to 10k times.

```
"filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "websites": "c2c53320-98dc-4eca-8022-9efc00dea0dc"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "languageCode": "en-us"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "erpNumber": "LIP_LAGSMS" // this one doesn't get blocked
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "erpNumber": "LIP_LAGSRG" //this one does get blocked
                      }
                    },...
```

Comment: You have a `must_not` containing `should`s inside a `must`... What constraints are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm expecting that both of those items shouldn't be returned in the results.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being an issue with the indexing

```
public override RootObjectMapping GetMapping()
{
    var productDefinition = base.GetMapping();
    var erpMapping = productDefinition.Properties.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Key.Name == nameof(ElasticsearchProduct.ErpNumber));
    productDefinition.Properties.Remove(erpMapping);
    productDefinition.Properties.Add(nameof(ElasticsearchProduct.ErpNumber).ToCamelCase(), new StringMapping { Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Analyzer = CustomAnalyzers.IscLowercaseAnalyzer });
    return productDefinition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should structure your query like this, i.e. move the `must_not` clause in the top-level `bool`:

```
"filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "websites": "c2c53320-98dc-4eca-8022-9efc00dea0dc"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "languageCode": "en-us"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
         {
             "term": {
                "erpNumber": "LIP_LAGSMS" // this one doesn't get blocked
              }
         },
         {
              "term": {
                  "erpNumber": "LIP_LAGSRG" //this one does get blocked
              }
         },...
      ]
```